# Can I play chrono trigger without an internet connection?

Tags: android, chrono-trigger

After a short period at the beginning of the game, a message `downloading additional data` appears.

How much of the game will I be able to play after this happens, without having to connect to the internet again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it would appear that the answer is unfortunately **none**.

Without an Internet connection present, I receive an "authentication failed" message when the app launches.